# Node.js - FTP through HTTP Tunnel (FTP over HTTP Proxy)

Tags: node.js, proxy, ftp

I am looking for an opportunity to connect FTP-Server via HTTP-Proxy-Server. I tried different npm packages (jsftp, ftp etc.), but the connection does not work. I have tried a few SOCKS packages but they seem outdated. Here is an example from the package jsftp. Unfortunately, the example does not work and I can not find any solution

```
const {SocksClient} = require('socks');
const ftp = new Ffp({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 3333,
  user: 'user',
  pass: 'password',
  createSocket: ({port, host}, firstAction) => {
    return SocksClient.createConnection({
      proxy: {
        ipaddress: '159.203.75.200'
        port: 1080,
        type: 5
      },

      command: 'connect',

      destination: {
        host,
        port
      }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score -2):

[This solution](https://www.example-code.com/nodejs/ftp_http_tunnel.asp) worked for me. However, it uses platform-dependent packages and is only commercially available starting from USD 289.

[This solution](https://blog.apify.com/tunneling-arbitrary-protocols-over-http-proxy-with-static-ip-address-b3a2222191ff) looked promising, but I couldn't get it to work properly. It created files I wanted to copy, but they always ended up being empty.